# How do I configure Flow in a newly created React JS app?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

After creating a new React app with `create-react-app`, there is no `.flowconfig` file. If I `flow` at command line, I get:

```
Could not find a .flowconfig in . or any of its parent directories.
See "flow init --help" for more info
```

If I do a `flow init`, it'll create a `.flowconfig` file, but with no default configuration:

```
[ignore]

[include]

[libs]

[options]
```

This *seems* to be all that I need to do to get flow working. In contrast, a newly created React Native app has a `.flowconfig` file with a lot of "default" configuration.

Is there a recommended default configuration for a React JS environment?

Comment: running ```yarn flow init``` fixed it for me which created the .flowconfig file needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t know much about React Native, but indeed this should be all that’s necessary to get Flow working with an app generated by Create React App. Of course you’ll also need to add `// @flow` to the files in which you want Flow to be enabled.

See also [“Adding Flow”](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-flow) in the User Guide.

Comment: Thanks Dan. That's what I needed to know. I do have Flow working but was just curious if any special configuration was needed/recommended for the React environment.